# Excel 365: Is there a way to fully protect (hide or encrypt) the url provided for a Data Source?

Tags: microsoft-excel, security, encryption, url, power-query

I'm importing data to Excel 356 using a data source "From webb". The url provided includes an API key that I do not want to share with others when I share the Excel file. I can use Protect Worksheet to prevent access to the Power Query. But the url is still reachable, and possible to copy, from Data\Get Data\Data Source Settings...

Is it possible to hide or encrypt the url also in the Data Source Settings list? (I still want the data source to work for those I've shared the Excel file with.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe copy the data to somewhere else?

Comment: @harrymc If I would copy the data somewhere else I would loose the possibility to update from the connection. Providing the static data, or possibly using the Excel file as a new data source and sharing the data that way, might be a feasible workaround. Thank you for the comment. However, I'd prefer if I could use the data source directly so I'm still hoping someone has  a solution for that.

Comment: Do you need to refresh the data? If not, you can break the links after importing...

Comment: @Lee that's an option I'd like to avoid, but I might need to if I find no other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this example https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents#example-3
And looking at this info regarding Power Query https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectorauthentication

We found a solution that probably will work for us, although not that smooth:

1. Make the data source to expect an url where the API key is expected like this:  "https://contoso.com/api/customers/get?api_key=******".
2. Open the Power Query Editor and add the Query from there, with info similar to this:
   *Csv.Document(Web.Contents("https://contoso.com/api/customers/get",[ApiKeyName="api_key"]),[Delimiter=";", Encoding=65001])*
   (Using the shortcut for adding data source "From webb" gets a bit tricky since the api_key is required but not yet set to the query).
3. Provide authentication settings for the API key (security level Private) to fetch the data, either by clicking the button prompting you that the authentication is not ok yet or from the Data Source Settings option in the menu. (From menu: First choose source, and the button for editing. Click Edit for the Authentication settings.) Select the option for Web API key and provide the actual key value (******). Choose  for what level of the url this key is valid.
4. Save and distribute the file.

You're promted that the password will not be encrypted at transfer. But when distributing this file to others they have to provide the authentication settings with the API key to be able to refresh the data - this seems good enough in our case.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I think at best you can do security by obscurity. Options, in order of ease of implementation/weakest security:

1. Use a link shortening facility to obscure the url
2. Put the web data in a hidden worksheet? I'm not sure if that would really help though.
3. Code your own refresh button that inputs the source url, does the refresh, deletes url. Remember to disable events and screenupdates, and pw protect your code.
4. Put the web update in another sharepoint workbook. Set it auto-update upon open. Setup an automation script to open save close the file on your pc several times a day. Link to this data from the shared workbook.
5. If you have 365, look into MS Power Automate to download the webdata and dump to a shared folder.

Comment: Ok, så the short answer is no. Thank you for all the "workaround" suggestions, I'll look into them. I'll keep this question open for a litle while longer, incase there are more suggestions (or possible solution) for this.

Comment: Using an URL shortening service would expose the API key to the people running the URL shortening service. That may be even more problematic than keeping it in the Excel file.

Comment: @Robert good point. Though obscure, and high unlikely that the service provider would inspect or "password mine" the urls in their databases, it is technically possible and more public than the spreadsheet.

Comment: Perhaps as an alternative, you can reencode the url yourself using simple hex ascii encoding, e.g. `www.%47%4F%4F%47%4C%45.com` is the same as `www.GOOGLE.com`. Still obvious for a determined haxor intending to steal your api key, but less so for the noob.